# Looping through controls on another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am moving some code over from an application I wrote in VBA to vb.net. In my original application I was able to loop through a set of 100 check boxes by doing the following:

```
Dim c As Control
Dim nm As String

For busRuleIdx = 1 To 100
 nm = "CheckBox" & busRuleIdx
 Set c = Form2.Controls(nm)
 If SomeRule Then
  c.Value = True
 Else
  c.Value = False
 End If
Next
```

I have tried something similar in VB.Net:

```
   Dim myForm As Form2
   Dim nm As String
   Dim c As CheckBox

   myForm = New Form2()
   For busRuleIdx = 1 To 100
    nm = "CheckBox" & busRuleIdx
    c = myForm.Controls(nm)
    If SomeRule Then
     c.Checked = True
    Else
     c.Checked = False
    End If
   Next
```

However this always results in c = nothing. I've seen the above work fine when referencing the current form i.e. me.Controls(nm) - but how am I able to use this type of code when referencing another form - in the example above Form2?

Thanks,

skinicod

Comment: Why not create a method on the form where the controls are, and pass the `SomeRule` result and let the form which own the controls manage its own controls.

Comment: As @Plutonix says. Start thinking in terms of objects. An instance of an object (myForm) owns its data (the controls) and should be responsible to change them

Comment: I appreciate that this is probably a better approach - but are you saying that what I am trying to achieve above is not possible?

Comment: Similarly, you have a problem in that you are creating a new `myform` and fiddling with different controls than what the user sees (`New` creates a new object/form). `c` may be nothing if the controls are in a container like a panel or groupbox

Comment: They are indeed in a container - if I had that to my code it works. c = myForm.GroupBox1.Controls(nm).

Comment: I will however investigate creating a separate method if you think this is the best way forward. Thanks.

Comment: I bet you cant see any checks though.  If there is already a Form2 showing, you are setting the controls on a different form instance, one that probably goes out of scope if that is in a method like a click event

Comment: There is not already a Form2 open - I am using information on my current form to pre determine a set of checks on Form2 when it is first opened.

Comment: If you create new object for the form2 then use that same object to open it .. like below      myformobj.show()

Comment: or else declare that form object globally and instead of calling the form2 call that object.